# Overwiting target directory in catch-all rule in GNU Makefile

Tags: gnu-make

Consider the following:

```
SRCS = somefile.c util/someother.c ../src/more.c

%.o : %.c
    $(GCC) -MD -c $< -o $@ -Wp,-MD,.deps/$*.d
    @cp .deps/$*.d .deps/$*.P; \
      sed -e 's/#.*//' -e 's/^[^:]*: *//' -e 's/ *\\$$//' \
          -e '/^$$/ d' -e 's/$$/ :/' < .deps/$*.d >> .deps/$*.P; \
      rm -f .deps/$*.d

-include $(SRCS:%.c=.deps/%.P)
```

How would I change the above so that the .o files end up in ./?  Currently they build in the directory the source file exists in and that's bad.

Answer (score 0):

I'd do it this way:

```
SRCS = somefile.c someother.c more.c

%.o : %.c
    [same as before]

-include $(SRCS:%.c=.deps/%.P)

vpath %.c util ../src
```